Examples of closed categories which are not monoidal closed?
There is a solid definition of "closed category" axiomatizing the idea that we can assign something resembling a hom-object to each pair of objects of a category. However, I am struggling to find a source of compelling examples of categories which are closed but not monoidal closed.
One recipe is the following: consider a selection of objects in a monoidal closed category, and construct a full subcategory by (including the monoidal unit and) iteratively applying the closed structure. For instance, the category of "sets of cardinality $3$ to the power of a power of $3$ (or zero)" is obtained in this way. Can you provide more natural/compelling examples?

Further flavour/context:
A recipe which doesn't seem to work is the following: for a monad $T$ on $\mathrm{Set}$, the collection of $T$-algebra homomorphisms with pointwise $T$-operations in the codomain seems like a promising candidate. Unfortunately, the typical condition required for this to produce a legitimate $T$-algebra is commutativity, which is also sufficient to make the category of $T$-algebras symmetric monoidal. I suspect that $T$ admitting a distributive law over itself is a weaker sufficient condition (what is the relationship between commutativity and self-distributivity for a monad $T$?), but I also suspect that one ends up with monoidal closure in that case. Are there sufficient conditions for $T$ to be closed without being monoidal? Should I be considering a $T$-algebra structure distinct from the pointwise one to derive the closed structure?
I suspect the reason that it's hard to find specific examples in the literature is the result of Day and Laplaza that any closed category can be embedded into a monoidal closed category, which takes the pressure off searching for such things. That said, the same type of result applies to monoidal categories, yet there is an abundance of examples of those...
One motivation for seeking more examples of closed categories is that they are a more natural setting to interpret "pure" $\lambda$-calculus than the typical cartesian-closed categories, so it would be convenient for the sake of applications in computer science to have examples where the absence of a monoidal structure makes a meaningful difference. Another is that some constructions in monoidal-closed categories can be expressed using either the monoidal structure or the closed structure, which suggests potential generalizations in both directions, but the monoidal versions are more common due to the abundance of examples of monoidal categories. I am curious to see what closed categories might yield!

I know nothing of the topic but I understand there are some good examples in logic (proof theory) of this. See for instance OCAs and AKSs and implicative algebras. I understand they start with implication as a basic building block with a left adjoint, wich in general is not a tensor product. For instance in case that left adjoint is a cartesian product, you get a heyting algebra. (Or something in between that and bicartesian closed category, I'm not sure.)

I would like to understand whether Miquel's implicative structures can provide a counterexample. Although it is apparently the case that a closed structure in which $[X,-]$ has a left adjoint for each $X$ need not be monoidal, the left adjoints to the implication do seem to me to be functorial in each argument (possibly thanks to the fact that these examples are posetal?)

That said, Miquel's quasi-implicative structures do appear to provide a counterexample, since they don't have a left adjoint. The main example given is that induced by a partial applicative structure. That gives me something to look into!

That's great! I haven't seen examples of quasi-implicative structures. But I understand there's not a monoidal category behind the implicative structures that have application as a left adjoint.
